# \hypersetup does not work well after \cleardoublepage

Tags: hyperref

In my MWE, \hypersetup is called after \cleardoublepage. But \hypersetup does not work well after \cleardoublepage, i.e., no PDF metadata in the document properties.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\cleardoublepage

\blindtext

\hypersetup{pdftitle={test}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\hypersetup` in the preamble of the document?

Comment: Because the document has some special requirements, \hypersetup must be called after \cleardoublepage. Do you have some better ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Here the title is just an example. In fact, I want to call \hypersetup to set other metadata.

Comment: same applies to all the document metadata, you can only have one entry. hypersetup to change link colours etc is not a problem.

Comment: Yes, but some values of metadata are given after \cleardoublepage in my document.

Comment: you can't need to do that. (you could for example just write them to the aux file so they get set at begin document)

Comment: could you plz show me how to do as you said?

Answer (score 3):

hyperref calls the command to set the metadata after the first page. So every \hypersetup on following page is ignored. You can set the title with primitives, but then it is up-to-you to ensure that the content is valid pdf. And you should better remove the metadata from the hyperref command to avoid to have two titles in the info dictionary:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\PDF@FinishDoc{/Title(\@pdftitle)}{}{}{\fail}%
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\cleardoublepage

\blindtext

\pdfinfo{/Title (test)}

\end{document}
```

But on the whole it is imho better to change whatever forces you to set the data later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I have the following error, i.e., Undefined control sequence. ^^I\pdfinfo.

Comment: how are you compiling?

Comment: When I use pdflatex to compile your MWE, it is correct. However, when I use xelatex, it will show me the error. My local environment is TeXLive 2017 + TeXStudio.

Comment: With xelatex you need `\special{pdf:docinfo<</Title (test)>>}`, but David's suggestion to go through the aux is certainly better.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry, I just don't know how to do as David's suggestion...How to go through the aux?

Answer (score 0):

An example using `aux` mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% usage of pdftitle in preamle is overwritten
\hypersetup{pdftitle={preamble}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setPdfTitle[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\ifx\string\@onlypreamble\string\@notprerr
    \string\else
      \string\AtBeginDocument{\string\def\string\@pdftitle{#1}}%
    \string\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a \newpage

\setPdfTitle{set title very late}

b
\end{document}
```

Another example, which delays the execution of `\PDF@FinishDoc` until the end of the document, can been found in this [github comment](https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum/issues/42#issuecomment-500592092).

These two examples are both independent of engines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Delaying to the end of the document can fail in certain cases - so one should check that the special didn't get lost.